# signal() call not firing

Tags: c, signals

I am attempting to write some code that forks a new process, but kills that new process after some amount of time if it is taking too long. This code works fine without the time restraint and executes `execve` without any problem, but when I put the 4 top lines of code in and try to call `cat` for my execve, the child simply is killed, assumedly by the call to alarm.

The `signal` call doesn't seem to be doing anything at all in this case, I have put numerous traces in `killproc` and it is not being called. How am I setting up this timing system incorrectly?

```
void killproc(int sig) {
    printf("running?");
}
```

**Code:** (in child)

```
if(MAX_TIME != -1){
    signal(SIGALRM, killproc);
    alarm(MAX_TIME);
}
// Process we are timing
int ret = execve(path, newargv, envp);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` is not safe in a signal handler; if the signal is delivered at the wrong time, internal structures will be invalid and `printf` will follow a bad pointer and crash.  Have you tested this with some other operation?  Even if it doesn't crash, you aren't flushing output or printing a newline, so the "running?" will probably be stuck in a stdio buffer.

Additionally, `signal()` is obsolete; you want to use `sigaction()`.  (The manpage for `sigaction` should also state which interfaces are safe to use in a signal handler.)

Those said, neither is the real problem; the problem is you're setting a signal handler and expecting it to survive across an `exec()`.  But `exec()` replaces the process's address space, *including your signal handler*; accordingly, it resets the handler, since it knows that no function pointer for a signal handler will be valid afterward.  `SIG_DFL` is probably what you want here (and in fact what you're getting), if you don't want to modify the program you're `exec()`ing; if you need something more, as it appears you believe you do, you will need to modify the program being `exec()`ed.

I suspect, however, that you really want something else:  whatever instrumentation you think you want to put in the signal handler, you really want to have in the parent process after the child exits and is reaped with `waitpid()`.

Comment: What I'm trying to do in this program is kill the forked process after some time, then print out something to the console saying that it didn't complete in time. Should I be attempting to put the signal() and alarm() calls before the parent's wait() command? I would use SIG_DFL, but I need to call my own custom function.

Comment: You can't call a custom function in the program you're running without modifying that program.  (How are you expecting your function to still exist after `exec()`?  The system just magically knows how much code is in and is called from the handler, to copy into some secret holding pen?)  Instead you let the signal kill the process, then check `WIFSIGNALED()` and `WTERMSIG()` when you reap it with `waitpid()`, to see if `SIGALRM` terminated it.